# What is the best way to handle a JavaScript to allow a user to access an html page?

Tags: javascript

Problem: Allow a user input and wait until a user input is received. If the user inputs matches then it allows the user to visit the website.  Otherwise, you will be navigated to the error.html.

I have tried the following javascript code.

```
var code = prompt("Please enter code: ")

function myfunction(code) {
  if (code !=123) {
    window.alert("error has occured.");
    window.location.href="error.html";
  }
}
```

The expected results should be the the prompt allows enough time and to enter the authorized code, if successful we will the page content.

The function is loading correctly but it doesnt allow enough time to enter the passcode because after a couple of seconds it automatically redirects to error.html.  Is this because of the body onload?

If everybody can suggest any extra validation i could that could be added i would appreciate it.

Comment: You would not use JavaScript **alone** to restrict access to a webpage. If they know even a little bit about the browser, they can get past this incredibly easily. Just don't do it.

Comment: But, to address your question, you have a `code` variable made outside of the function and a `code` parameter.  The `code` parameter takes preference so inside your function, you can't use the outside `code` with the prompt. And ensure that the `code` you're checking is wrapped in quotes because it is a string, not a number. You could do something like this: 

`function myfunction() { var code = prompt("Please enter code: "); if (code != '123') { window.alert("error has occured."); window.location.href="error.html"; } }`

Comment: Hi Marcus, Okay thanks for your response. What would be the most simplistic way to validate a user based on code.  This method for some reason doesnt allow enough time is it because im an body onload.

Comment: I updated the code in the comment. But, I would put the code at the very end of the body tag like this: `<body><script>function myfunction() { var code = prompt("Please enter code: "); if (code != '123') { window.alert("error has occured."); window.location.href="error.html"; } }</script></body>`

Comment: Prompt will freeze the page, there is no way to redirect while it is open... Not sure what would be going on if it is redirecting....

Comment: So it seems when i call something like <body onload="myFunction()"> the page is still rendering but once it finished loading the it gives that window alert and redirects to the error page

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by making this clear: handling authentication on the client side is **absolutely not secure**.  Users with even the slightest amount of knowledge will be trivially able to get to your website; all they'll have to do is view source to find either the "code" or the URL you're redirecting them to.

If this is supposed to just be a minor speed bump for the user, on the order of importance of hiding movie spoilers or something, that may be fine; but if you're trying to hide anything of importance you **must** use serverside authentication.

**Secure clientside authentication is impossible.**

With that out of the way:

The issue with your code is that the prompt and your function are not connected to each other at all.  You're firing `myfunction()` on page load, when what you really want is for it to run after the user input in the prompt.

Normally, when capturing user input, you need to write an event handler triggered by (for example) the input field's `change` event. `prompt` and `alert` are special cases, though; unlike just about everything else in the browser, they freeze javascript execution while open, and pick up again at the next line of code after the prompt is closed.

So when using `prompt` you wouldn't want to wrap the test of its results in a function at all; just drop the whole thing inline in your page:

```js
var userinput = prompt("Enter the not-actually-a-password")

/* JS execution pauses here until the user
   has closed the dialog box. */

if (userinput == 123) {
  console.log("successfully entered the not-actually-a-password");
} else {
  // wrong code; redirect:
  window.location.href = "https://example.com"
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, what would be a way in the server side to authenticate somebody.

Comment: That's a huge subject, I'm sorry; I don't know of any simple or beginner-friendly ways to do it well (when I have to, I outsource the problem using OAuth, it's the sort of thing I'd rather leave to experts)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Marcus Parsons, this doesn't seem to be a good practice.
Still, I think you can hide your content to some extent until the code verification by using a document ready event listener.

```
function myFunc(){
var code = prompt("Please enter code: ");
if(code==""||code==null||code!='1234'){
  //Handle Error
  window.alert("error has occured.");
  window.location.href="error.html";
}}
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
         document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
                  if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
                      myFunc();
                  }
              });
}
```

If you want to authenticate the users on the client without having your own backend, you could use firebase authentication. You wouldn't have to worry about the server side stuff.

Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/